# Improving cypher queries and avoiding cartesian product

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm pretty new to neo4j and cypher. I have a table Transaction and a table Person that i'd like to link as follow (only the `rel3` relationship does matter in the end) :

```
MATCH (t:Transaction),(p1:Person)
WHERE p1.id = t.id1
CREATE (p1)-[:rel1]->(t)

MATCH (t:Transaction),(p2:Person)
WHERE p2.id = t.id2
CREATE (t)-[:rel2]->(p2)

MATCH (p1:Person)-[:rel1]->(t:Transaction)-[:rel2]->(p2:Person)
CREATE (p1)-[:rel3]->(p2)
```

However I was wondering if there was a way to avoid this double cartesian product and still achieve the same goal. Performance is indeed a big concern for me since I got millions of rows to process. So I tried some modifications and ended up with that version :

```
MATCH (t:Transaction)
WITH t
MATCH (p1:Person {id : t.id1})
WITH n1, t
MATCH (p2:Person {id : t.id2})
CREATE (p1)-[:rel3]->(p2)
```

It's easier to read and understand, but according to the `PROFILE` command, it does the exact same thing. Any idea to improve that code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you're doing that in two steps if you can do

```
MATCH (t:Transaction),(p1:Person),(p2:Person)
WHERE p1.id = t.id1
AND p2.id = t.id2
CREATE (p1)-[:REL3]->(p2)
```

If you have a unique constraint on the id property for the Person label that's about as fast as you'll get this. My biggest question however ... why don't you create the relationship the moment you create the Transaction itself, instead of storing **foreign keys** (a big no, no in graph database) and then doing the work afterwards?

Hope this helps.

Regards, Tom

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would suggest to `MATCH (p1:Person {id : line.id1}) , (p2:Person {id : line.id2})` and `CREATE (p1)-[:rel3]->(p2)` directly after my `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///transaction.csv"AS line` ? I tried it and it seemed pretty slow, not sure why...

Comment: @Aegir Make sure you have indexes or unique constraints on :Person(id) for that to go fast